# Queue of callbacks Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    before_destroy :post_method1
    after_destroy  :post_method2
end


class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :post
    after_destroy :comment_method
end
```

How will the callbacks and destroy methods be ordered in the two models after the `post.destroy` like `(if post.comments.any? = true)`???

Comment: You don't show any dependence between the `Comment` and `Post`. Are any of your `post_method*`s calling `comments.destroy_all`?

Comment: Yes. My apologize. Edit question.

Comment: My guess is it runs `post_method1` then for each comment runs `comment_method` then runs `post_method2` just out of what I expect behavior of something like this to be.